# Cartesian Form of a Line

Tags: geometry, parametric

I have a general question: when given the parametric form of a line such that:

$$ x = a_1 + \lambda t_1 $$

$$ y = a_2 + \lambda t_2 $$

$$ z = a_3 + \lambda t_3 $$

The Cartesian form is:

$$ \frac{x-a_1}{t_1} = \frac{y-a_2}{t_2} = \frac{z-a_3}{t_3} $$

What happens when one of the $t$ is zero? For example, let $t_2 = 0$. Then what happens?

Comment: Look back at the first three equations $t_2=0$ will give $y=a_2$ ... i.e. The value of $y$ is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set one of the $t_i$ to be zero you need to look at the original equations *first* before considering the Cartesian form.  In this case, if $t_2 = 0$ then the second equation becomes $y=a_2$ which is still the equation of a line -- but the Cartesian form with this is just $$\frac{x-a_1}{t_1} = \lambda = \frac{z-a_3}{t_3} \quad \mbox{and} \quad y = a_2$$

This technique of considering alternate forms of an equation to help you understand the behaviour at singular points (e.g. where the denominator of a fraction becomes zero) is used moderately often in mathematics.

Comment: And quite obviously, putting a zero on the denominator would be incorrect right?

Comment: @NeevParikh Putting a zero in the denominator is nonsense.

Comment: Yes.  It might help to look at the slope of the lines here: $y=a_2$ is a horizontal line, while the others are not.  Putting zero on the denominator would result in an indeterminate form.

Comment: The displayed equation chain is wrong. $y-a_2=0$ whereas the remaining fractions express the line parameter $\lambda$ which varies.

Comment: @ccorn -- thank-you!  I've corrected it (and added in the dependency on $\lambda$ for clarity.  Please do feel free to edit these corrections in yourself when you spot them!

Answer (score 1):

Just go back to the original form and write
$$\frac{x-a_1}{t_1}=\frac{z-a_3}{t_3}, y=a_2$$

Comment: Right thanks. I guess putting zero on the bottom would be incorrect.